# Status december 2020 - 'The deployment ID is not associated with the current project'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to publish a simple Google Add-on.
I have followed each step of [this Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk) and in the third step: [Enable and configure the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk), in [About App Configuration](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk#about_app_configuration) you have to enter the [Deployment ID](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk#add-on), the [project script ID](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk#editor_add-on_docs_sheets_slides_forms), the version and some links.
On clicking save, I get the same Issue over and over again; `The deployment ID is not associated with the current project`. I've tried this several times over several days and it still doesn't work.
Does anybody have a solution?
Could it be that Google is overloaded?
Thanks, greetings Gabriel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to convert you Apps Script project into a standard GCP project

This you can do by

---

- going on `Resources-> Cloud Platform project...`

---

[image]

---

- and inserting a GCP project number:

---

[image]

---

- You can find the project number in the Dashboard of your GCP console

---

[image]

---

**IMPORTANT**

You need to bind the Apps Script to exactly the same GCP project under which you want to deploy the Add-on with the Marketplace SDK

Comment: Thanks, @ziganotschka, you're a lifesaver!
Is there a place where I could find this in the Google Dev Page, but I didn't see it?

Comment: You can read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) and [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).